# Increase number every 7 days in PHP

Tags: php, date, time, range, date-range

I select the date range from Input field for ex:

```
<?php

    $Startdate = '2017-06-12'; // date format Y-m-d
    $Enddate = '2017-06-17';
    Number = 1;

?>
```

For example if I select the above date range or any date between above range the number should be 1; when I change the range for next 7 days or any date between next 7 days the number should be 2 and so on.

Answer (score 0):

By using following code you can get days between dates and implement your logic.

```
<?php
$Startdate = '2017-06-12';
$Enddate = '2017-06-17';

$date1=date_create($Startdate);
$date2=date_create($Enddate);
$diff=date_diff($date1,$date2);

$days = $diff->format('%a');

echo $days;
?>
```

Comment: i have a variable named $EDITION_NUMBER i want to increase the number after every 7 days

Comment: divide the days with 7 and you will get weeks